# Are there common scripts one can use in its postinst, postrm, etc.?

Tags: package-management, scripts, deb, packaging

I'm working on many separate projects each of which comes with a separate Debian package for Ubuntu.

For all of the projects including a service, I end up doing similar things in their `preinst`, `postinst`, `prerm`, and `postrm` scripts. For example, I create a user and a group and then a log sub-directory under `/var/log` where I create a first empty log file with the correct user and group (otherwise `logrotate` fails to rotate those files).

Here is an example on how to safely create the user and group in the `preinst` script (it goes in the `preinst` so that way some of the unpacked files can make use of that user:group):

```
ENVIRONMENTNAME=communicatord
USERNAME=communicatord
GROUPNAME=communicatord

# add user and group
#
if ! getent group "${GROUPNAME}" >/dev/null
then
    addgroup --system "${GROUPNAME}"
fi
#
if ! getent passwd "${USERNAME}" >/dev/null
then
    adduser --quiet \
        --system \
        --ingroup "${GROUPNAME}" \
        --disabled-login \
        --disabled-password \
        --home "/var/lib/${ENVIRONMENTNAME}" \
        --no-create-home \
        -gecos "Communicator Daemons and Tools" \
            "${USERNAME}"
fi
```

Doing all that work is quite repetitive when I could have a script running all the commands at once. Maybe something like:

```
setup-service <environmentname> <username> <groupname> <logname>
```

At the moment, I'm thinking of creating one package which offers all of these scripts in once place. Then I can run that `setup-service` script from all the other projects. But I'd like to avoid creating yet another package (it's additional maintenance, etc.).

What I'm wondering about is whether there is already such a package which would offer a set of default scripts that are fairly common to many Debian/Ubuntu packages?

I, of course, use the `/usr/share/debconf/confmodule`. I also know of the `autoscripts` which get added when you use specific files or options (`systemd` is automatically handling the enabling of a service and starting it, a `debian/logrotate` file gets installed under `/etc/logrotate.d`, there is support for `crontab` files, etc.).

Would it be possible (and easy enough) to extend the `autoscripts` mechanism for users, logs, etc.? For example, I could have a file named `users` which tells the `autoscripts` to create one or more users on installation and automatically remove those users on a purge.

Comment: I doubt there is any... can I offer a suggestion? Create a gitlab account and post them online. It might attract others.  2nd suggestion: make /var/lib/ also a variable. And if these are more scripts with each a user and group using 1 group name might be handy too.

Comment: The existing scripts (with much copy/paste at the moment) are available in my [Snap! C++ environment](https://github.com/m2osw) on github. Before I had one user, but I'm breaking up many of the packages and as a result I'll have many... so many scripts would have duplicates. I was just looking at the `dh_...` scripts, I think I'll go that route. Because that way the scripts will be duplicated in each pre/post/inst/rm, but automatically...

Comment: @Rinzwind I actually found a project named `dh-sysuser` which at least takes care of the user issue for me! Available since Ubuntu 18.04. (see my answer for details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional research about the Deb Helpers, I found a package named `dh-sysuser` and it does exactly what I.

First, install that extension:

```
sudo apt-get install dh-sysuser
```

Then in your `debian/rules` file, add the module like so:

```
dh $@ --with sysuser
```

*(Note: if you already have a `--with ...` then add a comma and the name like in `--with python2,sysuser`)*

Finally, create a `debian/<package>.sysuser` file with the user name and an option. In my case, I want the home directory created like so:

```
# User Name     Options
sitter          home
```

You can specify an exact home directory (`home=/home/dir`) instead of leaving it to the `dh_sysuser` script to create a default one (`home=/var/lib/<package>`). Another option is `defaults`.

With that in hands already, it's much better / easier to create my users.

Also, you must make sure that the `dh-sysuser` package is installed at build time, so edit your `debian/control` file and add:

```
Build-Depends: ... dh-sysuser ...
```

Note that when I install `dh-systemd` I get everything I need, except that extension! So here you go, you should make sure you have that one installed as well.

I don't think I'll find a way to handle the logrotate mess, but with the existing `dh_...` scripts, I think I can easily add that feature.

Sources:

- [Manual Page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dh-sysuser/dh_sysuser.1.en.html)
- [Example](https://medium.com/opsops/dh-sysuser-6bd3e3d623dd)